# Generate a different random number each time a function runs using sprite kit and GKRandomSource

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I cant quite see it in my head. I'm making a simple function that generates bubbles floating upwards from the ocean floor. I want the path the bubble takes before it fades out to be different each time they float up. I wrote this function:

```
 func bubbles(){

    var bubbleX = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 10)
    var bubbleY = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 30)
    let bubbleTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble.png")
    let bubbleSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: bubbleTex)
    bubbleSprite.zPosition = 1
    bubbleSprite.setScale(0.5)
    addChild(bubbleSprite)
    let moveUpLeft = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
    let moveUpRight = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
    let moveBack = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), duration: 0)
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.8)
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUpLeft, moveUpRight, moveBack])
    let group = SKAction.group([sequence, fadeOut])
    let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([fadeIn, group])
    let sequenceRepeated = SKAction.repeatForever(seq2)

    bubbleSprite.run(sequenceRepeated, completion: {
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.4)
    })

}
```

When the game loads all of the bubbles have a random path, but then each instance of the bubbles repeats the same random path generated on the first function run. How can I make bubbleX and bubbleY random each time the function runs?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a repeat forever the way you are doing it. Repeat forever does not call the functions over again, only the values that were stored in it.  You instead need to call a block of code that generates a new path each time:

```
 func bubbles(){
    let bubbleTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble.png")
    let bubbleSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: bubbleTex)
    bubbleSprite.zPosition = 1
    bubbleSprite.setScale(0.5)
    self.addChild(bubbleSprite)
    var block : (SKNode, CGFloat) -> Void = { (node,elapsedTime) in
        if elapsedTime > 0 {return}
        var bubbleX = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 10)
        var bubbleY = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 30)


        let moveUpLeft = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
        let moveUpRight = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
        let moveBack = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), duration: 0)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUpLeft, moveUpRight, moveBack])
        let group = SKAction.group([sequence, fadeOut])
        let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([fadeIn, group])
        node.run(seq2)
    }
    let sequenceRepeated = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.customAction(withDuration:2.4,actionBlock:block))
    bubbleSprite.run(sequenceRepeated)
}
```

Basically what is going on here is we have a looped action that will attach another action every 2.4 seconds (2.0 duration + 0.4 wait time)

Edit:  Uses run(block)

```
 func bubbles(){
    let bubbleTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble.png")
    let bubbleSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: bubbleTex)
    bubbleSprite.zPosition = 1
    bubbleSprite.setScale(0.5)
    self.addChild(bubbleSprite)
    var block = { 
        var bubbleX = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 10)
        var bubbleY = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 30)


        let moveUpLeft = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
        let moveUpRight = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
        let moveBack = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), duration: 0)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUpLeft, moveUpRight, moveBack])
        let group = SKAction.group([sequence, fadeOut])
        let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([fadeIn, group])
        bubbleSprite.run(seq2)
    }
    let seq = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(block),SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.4)])
    let sequenceRepeated = SKAction.repeatForever(seq))
    bubbleSprite.run(sequenceRepeated)
}
```

Original answer:

GKRandomSource.sharedRandom() uses arc4random to generate its numbers, so if you call arc4random prior to reading the source, it should generate a new sequence.

```
func bubbles(){
    let _ = arc4random()
    var bubbleX = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 10)
    var bubbleY = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 30)
    let bubbleTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble.png")
    let bubbleSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: bubbleTex)
    bubbleSprite.zPosition = 1
    bubbleSprite.setScale(0.5)
    addChild(bubbleSprite)
    let moveUpLeft = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
    let moveUpRight = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: bubbleX, dy: bubbleY), duration: 1)
    let moveBack = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), duration: 0)
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.8)
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUpLeft, moveUpRight, moveBack])
    let group = SKAction.group([sequence, fadeOut])
    let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([fadeIn, group])
    let sequenceRepeated = SKAction.repeatForever(seq2)

    bubbleSprite.run(sequenceRepeated, completion: {
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.4)
    })

}
```

Comment: Ok, I must say,  I have provided two different answers, and everytime I reread your question,  I get more and more confused,  If this is not what you are looking for, then let me know if my first answer was the one that you were looking for.

Comment: Your original answer yielded no change. I copy and pasted your second answer but the bubble Isn't showing up when I run it. From the looks of it I think it's what I need though, I just need to figure out how to get the bubble to spawn with it. The goal of this is every time the bubble fades out and goes back to x:,y:0, it fades in and needs to ascend taking a slightly different path than it did the last time. It's just to add a bit of realism instead of all the bubbles taking the same exact floating path.

Comment: @genericguy25 ok. I am following it now,  the actions loop the bubbles, so yes 2nd answer

Comment: Check if the elapsedTime starts at zero,  I thought it did but I could be mistaken.

Comment: The second answer only runs once and then nothing.

Comment: we are in an infinite loop though

Comment: my answer runs forever but the bubble follows the same path every time. I'm trying to get the bubbles to take a different path each time the action runs in it's loop.

Comment: oh your timing is off it takes 2 seconds, so your moving is not in sync with fadeout

Comment: The code should now be firing the custom action every 2.4 seconds,  does the elapse time reset?  i always thought it was a relative elapse time, but maybe it is passing in the duration of the repeat forever

Comment: I removed the fade out as a test and after the first action the bubble returns to 0,0 and doesn't not continue movement.

Comment: print the elapsetime, make sure it is being reset to 0

Comment: it prints 0.0 twice and then stops

Comment: I added a run block example

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: Any time my friend